# GridSearchCV algorithm for LSTM

Tags: lstm, gridsearchcv

I am trying to create lstm deep neural network model with gridsearchcv algorithm. However, when I run the code, gridsearchcv algorithm, as seen in the photo, the loss value is very large and the accuracy value is very small. As far as I know, the loss should be small and accuracy should be large. I couldn't find where the error is. Can anybody help.My code is below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, median_absolute_error, mean_absolute_error, mean_absolute_percentage_error, mean_squared_error
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,LSTM, LayerNormalization
from keras.models import Sequential
from datetime import datetime
# from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier, KerasRegressor
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import seaborn as sb
df = pd.read_excel('izmir_saatlik_tuketim_verisi.xlsx', sheet_name='Veri (2)')
time_index = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01 00:00', periods=len(df),  freq='H')  
time_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(time_index)
df['time']=time_index
df['hour']= df['time'].dt.hour
df['week']= df['time'].dt.week
df['dayofweek']= df['time'].dt.dayofweek
df['dayofyear']= df['time'].dt.dayofyear
df['month']= df['time'].dt.month
df['Unnamed: 0']=df['time']
df.rename(columns ={'Unnamed: 0':'Time'},inplace=True)
df.drop(['time'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df['Nispi_Nem(%)'].fillna(df['Nispi_Nem(%)'].median(), inplace=True)
X=df.iloc[:,2:9].values
y=df.iloc[:,1].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

#---------------------------Normalize of data----------------------
scaler=MinMaxScaler()
X_train=scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test=scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
y_train=scaler.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(-1,1))
y_test=scaler.fit_transform(y_test.reshape(-1,1))

X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))

#-------------------------------Built in model-------------------------
param_grid = {'batch_size' : [50,100,250],
                # 'activation':['tanh','sigmoid','relu'],
                # 'optimizer':['adam','rmsprop','adagrad'],
                'epochs' : [20,50,100],
                # 'units':[16,32,64,128,256]
                }
Dropout_rate=0.5
def create_model(units=16, optimizer='adam'):
    lstm_model = Sequential()
    lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=units,activation='tanh',return_sequences=True, 
                        input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=units,activation='tanh',return_sequences=False))
    lstm_model.add(Dense(1, activation='Softmax'))
    lstm_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss="mae", metrics=["acc"])
    return lstm_model

tf.random.set_seed(111)

#-------------------------Hyperparamaters Optimization------------------------
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=1)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv = 2, verbose=0)

grid_result=grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxVyJ.jpg)
```

I am trying to create lstm deep neural network model with gridsearchcv algorithm. However, when I run the code, gridsearchcv algorithm, as seen in the photo, the loss value is very large and the accuracy value is very small. As far as I know, the loss should be small and accuracy should be large. [loss and acc values image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JLm9.jpg)